# android Q content above navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, navigationbar, android-10.0

we are targeting our application at api 28 and draw content under status bar. For this we are using following flag and styles :

```
window.addFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

---

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

everything is okay on Android Pie (content layout under status bar and above navigation bar). In android Q, navigation bar is translucent and shows over the application content [image]

Comment: you want to hide navigation bar?

Comment: Hide or keep old version ( concent strat above the navigation bar)

Answer (score 4):

In android api 29, Bottom bar is overlapping the content.

Add this code in your activity

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);


    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView(), new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
            v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, v.getPaddingBottom() + insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom());
            return insets;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me running on Android 12. Slightly modified kotlin solution to replace deprecated "insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom()" :

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { v, insets ->

            val systemBarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, systemBarInsets.bottom)

            insets
        }

Answer (score 3):

the "problem" underlies the behavior of the FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, mixed with the new gesture functionality in api 29

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-handling-visual-overlaps-4aed565c134c

a little solution is:

```
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

and don't set

```
android:fitsSystemWindows
android:windowTranslucentStatus
android:windowIsTranslucent
```

Comment: Still same in Android 29

Comment: The most important thing, don't set `getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

Answer (score 0):

You should this to you main activity

```
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

and then create a new styles.xml file for v29

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- values-v29/themes.xml -->
  <style name="AppTheme"
      parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="android:navigationBarColor">
          @android:color/black
      </item>

      <!-- Optional, if drawing behind the status bar too -->
      <item name="android:statusBarColor">
          @android:color/black
      </item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

source:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e