# systemWindowInsetBottom is always zero

Tags: android, configuration, navigation, android-10.0

I set setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener to root view of application and get update on navigation bar changes, but insets.systemWindowInsetBottom is always 0

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    layoutMain?.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->
        layoutMain.updatePadding(bottom = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom)
        insets
    }
}
```

layoutMain is Constraint layout and root view group in MaincActivity

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ... >
```

on more thing, I use following flag :

```
    window.addFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

[[using following tutorial :]](https://chris.banes.dev/2019/04/12/insets-listeners-to-layouts/)
also my another [question for the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784715/android-q-content-above-navigation-bar?noredirect=1#comment102003064_57784715)

Comment: Please try it `onResume()` or `onCreate()`

Comment: Doesn't matter -_- it is callback

Comment: it is view related. And you try to get callback from view.  So try it onCreate or onResume whe view are initiated :)

Comment: Same result anyway

Answer (score 0):

After creating a sample project and following your reference tutorial  i found followings things.

I found some reason of getting `systemWindowInsetBottom` value is zero.

1. The value is depend on `bottomNavigation`. If your system back button (Soft layer) overlap the `bottomNavigation` or your `bottomNavigation` is completely hide then you wuill get correct value of `systemWindowInsetBottom`.
2. But if your `bottomNavigation` visible and  above from system soft bottom layer (back button,home button etc.) then you you will get 0.

The below example is showing when we get can zero and when we can get actual value.

if you add this line you will get some value because bottomNavigation not visible `mBinding.getRoot().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION)`;

But if you remove that line or add this line you will get always zero.
 `mBinding.getRoot().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);`

> So the vaue is depend on bottomNavigation visibility state

```
private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        mBinding.getRoot().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        if (navHostFragment != null) {
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBinding.bottomNavigation, navHostFragment.getNavController());
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {

            mBinding.mainLayout.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                @Override
                public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
                    Log.d("BottomTest", "padding: " + insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom());

                    return insets;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the View's source code, we know that only you set the flags (SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN) that can impact the layout in relation to system UI, you can get the actual value。